# AngularJS write object values by specified array of attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to write object values by specified attributes in array. I have model with list of contacts and each contact has Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Address (related entity), CreatedOn. I want to write all entities but only attributes specified in array ["FirstName", "Email", "Address.Name"].

HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="contact in contactList">
        <td ng-repeat="attribute in arrayOfAttributes">
            {{contact[attribute]}}
        </td>
</tr>
```

This piece of code works fine but does not work for related entity "Address.Name". I do not think that I should do some conditions in ng-repeat. I hope there is an easier way to do that.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is contactList? Can you paste your controller code? Fiddle will be best if you can create that shows your problem

Comment: You need to create function which extracts value as you can not directly access address.name. What I understand is address is an object and inside there is a name which you want to access.

Comment: contactList is array of contact objects. Example: [{Id:1, FirstName: 'First name', Email: 'email@email.com'}, ..., ...]

Comment: Yes, Address is related entity of Contact entity...